# Slow FTP Over Direct Windows Connection

Tags: windows, ftp, ethernet, filezilla

I am connecting two Windows PCs (XP and Vista, if that matters) via direct connection (the 169.254.*.* IP addresses).  The XP box is serving FTP via FileZilla Server, and the Vista box is downloading, using either Windows Explorer or FileZilla Client.  This works, however I'm seeing a consistent speed of 1.2MB/s, despite the fact that both the XP and Vista boxes have Gigabit connections.  I'm using a CAT5 cable admittedly, but worst case I feel like I should be seeing ~100Mb/s transfer speeds at least.

Does anyone know what the bottleneck here is, and if there's any way to get more reasonable transfer speeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you have one of the interfaces configured to use 10Mb/s wire protocol; or that it's auto-negotiating at a low speed. You may want to manually configure them to use the 1000BASE-T in the device manager and see if that helps your case.

Comment: Spot on - Intel's driver was set to auto-detect the connection speed, and for whatever reason was defaulting to 10Mb/s.  Thanks alot!